# Validate a directory of windows

Tags: c#, .net, path, directory

I'm looking for a way how to check if an Path is a valid windows directory.

Currently, I'm this code:

```
public static bool IsDirectory(string path) {
      return Path.IsPathRooted(path) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(Path.GetFileName(path));
}
```

I need to improve it to that works the following paths:

```
C:\foo\baa.txt\baa
\baa\x\
\baa\x
\baa
```

if you seen that does not works to some path,please tell me.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to know if the string is a valid directory string, or if it's an existing directory (ie: it's already existing on the file system?)

Comment: @ReedCopsey:if the string is a valid directory string.

Answer (score 3):

To check whether the string is a valid string for a directory path,
you can use [Path.GetDirectoryName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx) to verify this.  If the method raises an exception or returns `String.Empty`, then it is not a valid path.

To see if the string is a real, existing directory in the file system, you can use [Directory.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx).

Comment: Curious as to the downvotes - GetDirectoryName will do the proper validation for you...

Comment: I noticed everyone got them. I thought it was you or Bill ONeal doing it to everyone elses answer.

Comment: @jp2code Not me - I didn't downvote any answer, as the original question was not incredibly clear...

Comment: I'm confused as well, I thought I had updated my answer to correct the original concern...

Comment: @jp2code: I downvoted all the answers which were wrong -- that is, which checked for whether a directory existed rather than whether a path was valid. I upvoted this answer because it is a correct answer. Not sure about anyone else.

Comment: @BillyONeal Yeah - its strange - multiple people have been downvoting every answer, with no apparent rationale...

Comment: I gave everyone a +1 for entering valid ideas. I think wording of the original question was a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the cases where a simple Regex pattern is the easiest solution:

```
public static bool IsDirectory(string path)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(path, 
        "([a-z]:)?\\\\[^/:*?\"<>|\\r\\n]*", 
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to allow e.g. `..\foo\bar`.

Comment: It was not in the question but this one does -> "([a-z]:|\\.{1,2})?\\\\[^/:*?\"<>|\\r\\n]*"

Answer (score 0):

Use the BCL `Directory` class, it has an `Exists()` method.

```
if (Directory.Exists(@"c:\foo\baa.txt\baa"))
{
    // etc
}
```

**UPDATE**: My original assumption was that the OP was looking to see if the directory existed, given that he wants to know just if the syntax is valid, you can use `Path.GetDirectoryName()` (as Reed first pointed out) to return the directory portion of the path.

```
var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"c:\foo\baa.txt\baa");
```

Which throws if any invalid characters.  If you want to make sure the path is *only* a directory (not a path to a file), you can compare the path to the returned directory.

Comment: The path can be valid even if the directory doesn't exist.

Comment: @BillyONeal: Fair point, I had assumed from the OP's question he wanted to know if it was an valid existing directory, my mistake.

Comment: Can the second down-voter comment?  The answer was updated to reflect the original concern.

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare No clue here - very, very strange.  I voted up your and Billy's answers, as our three address the actual question, but didn't vote any down, as it's not worded clearly enough to warrant that, IMO... The multiple downvotes is very odd for this, as I feel that we directly address the issue.

Comment: @ReedCopsey: Agreed, I hope it's not just answer posturing, you just never know on SO.  I bumped up the other answers as well where relevant to help compensate.

Answer (score 0):

```
return System.Directory.Exists(path);
```

---

EDIT:
By using the Path class, you can test if a path string is syntactically valid  (Path.GetFileName and Path.GetDirectoryName raise exceptions if not). However, you cannot determine if it stands for a file or a directory.

[image]

The picture shows a path which looks like standing for a text file, but is actually a directory. On the other hand, you could have a path like "C:\abc\xyz", which looks like a directory path, but could stand for a file without an extension as well.

Exceptions are root directories "C:\" and other path strings, which end with a backslash. However, a directory path is also syntactically valid if it does not end with a backslash.

Conclusion: In most cases, you will have to test your path string against an actually existing directory or file in order gain certainty.

Comment: The path can be valid even if the directory doesn't exist. Plus, what if the path is a file? That'd be perfectly valid too.

Comment: If the path is a file, then you would use `File.Exists()`. Plus, his comment "if the string is a valid directory string" was posted after I had posted my answer.

Comment: The original question was "validate", not "check the existence of."

Comment: @BillyONeal: I just made the test. If you pass a path of an existing file to `Directory.Exists()`, then is will return `false`!

Comment: What does that have to do with the fact that you answered for existence, not validity? The validity of the path has nothing to do with where the path points.

Comment: @BillyONeal: Checking the existance can also be "validate", depending on what is required.

Answer (score 0):

The rules for a valid path are documented on MSDN in the article [Naming Files, Paths and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx). What constitutes "valid" in your case depends on how strict you want to be. Windows NT technically supports pretty much anything in terms of a path, excepting a few reserved characters.

That said, the Win32 subsystem of NT is a bit less forgiving, and has a few rules you'd need to follow, such as the reserved filenames CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9, etc.

At the end of the day though you shouldn't check if the path is valid. Just try to open or otherwise operate on the path the user gives you, and if you can't open/operate on what they give, then show an error message. This really is no different than the user handing you a corrupted file and asking you to make heads or tails of it.